# Cassandra TTL changed Automatically

Tags: cassandra

I am having a column family in cassandra with default ttl as 3024000(35 days),compaction strategy is LCS and table structure is something like this

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
logdate text,
cookieid text,
count1 int,
count2 int,
count3 int,
PRIMARY KEY (logdate, cookieid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (cookieid ASC)
```

but when i am checking the ttl of 35 old days data it is still showing 20 days i am not getting why this is happening. Do anybody have idea about this? Is this because of compaction ?

Answer (score 2):

This could  happen if you have reinserted the same row.

For example

```
INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES(100,..........some value) -- lets say inserted 10 days back.
```

If the row is not inserted again the TTl could have shown 25 days, but what might had happend is the row gets inserted again.

```
INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES(100,..........some other value ) -- lets say inserted 5 days back.
```

The TTL will be 30 days.

TTL value gets reset at every insert of the row (same row key).

Comment: yeah thats true but i never inserted my data again

Comment: I don't see other reason, your date column (which is partition key), how do you calculate that?

Comment: this is calculated from application. application sets it equal to current date

Comment: @deenbandhu Really not sure then. I tried compation as well, but it is giving correct results in my case.

Comment: what is writetime of the value?

Comment: I dont understan, you asking the concept "write time of the value" ? Cassandra keeps every cell with a tuple, { Column name, column value, write timestamp }

Comment: Yes, writetime function. You are telling that ttl is changed, and you didn't written a row except the first time, so the write time should be 35+ days old, otherwise you've performed a rewrite.

Comment: @nevsv thats correct, unless the row is re written, TTL will not change.

Comment: i'm sorry, i was asking @deenbandhu for this info :).

Comment: I know this concept that writetime will be changed only if row is rewritten into cassandra but there is no such operation happened i know i just want to confirm if compaction change this field or not ?

Comment: Compaction has nothing to do with ttl, otherwise it was never working.